# Show the sequence of functions has a unique solution using the contraction mapping principle

Tags: analysis

I've got a problem like this:

Show that the system of equations
$$x_1=\frac{1}{4}x_1-\frac{1}{4}x_2+\frac{2}{15}x_3+3$$
$$x_2=\frac{1}{4}x_1+\frac{1}{5}x_2+\frac{1}{2}x_3-1$$
$$x_3=-\frac{1}{4}x_1+\frac{1}{3}x_2-\frac{1}{3}x_3+2$$
has a unique solution, using the contraction mapping principle.

I honestly don't know how to apply the principle here but here is my guess:
Is the function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and it would eventually converge to a unique $(x_1^*,x_2^*,x_3^*)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases

Comment: and yes, you consider  your $f,$  where the distance function is now the magnitude of the difference vector $f(x) - f(y) = A (x-y)$  where $A$ is the square matrix of coefficients . The extra constant terms $3,-1,2$ cancel in the subtraction